# Performance of indexOf() vs. an Associative Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, associative-array, indexof

I have a series of values which correspond to certain numbers.  There are never two values that correspond to the same number.  There are no gaps between the numbers.
E.G.
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} 
*as opposed to* 
{a: 1, b: 3, c: 4, d: 7}

Right now, I store the values in an array and find the index of that value.  The index in the array is the number that value corresponds with.

Assume the arrays are prepopulated.  My questions is which is more efficient to **find the corresponding numbers** in Javascript:

Store the values in specific positions of an array and find the index with indexOf().

---or---

Store the values and numbers as key value pairs in an associative array.

Comment: The answer is in jsperf for your specific case.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ ... the more elements there are, the slower the array approach will be.

Answer (score 0):

from what you are saying...
a should be zero as the array starts from index zero and not 1

CASE numeric array:{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4} 
for loop is suitable

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 5; 
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    // Iterates over every single numeric indexes from 0 to 5
}
```

CASE a value is skipped:{a: 1, b: 3, c: 4, d: 7}

for..in is suitable

```
 var a = [];
    a[5] = 5;
    for (var x in a) {
       ignores 0-4,shows only 5
    }
```

CASE Associative array: indexof is suitable

NOTE: It is considered bad practice for iterating through arrays,but not for iterating through members of an object.